# JQuery Horizontal Accordion CSS

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I'm trying to build a simple multi-level UL Horizontal Accordion (or slide menu) in Jquery.  Hunter Daley graciously provided the Jquery code, but I can't seem to figure out the css.  I know this is newb, but I'm really stuck.

When Ul li Ul slides out it creates a linebreak, I'd like to have everything display inline, with no breaks.  I've tried whitespace: nowrap, display inline etc It just won't seem to do it.  Any ideas?

As per, Glavic's answer: I was trying to to use floats, but if I do Safari bugs out and flash the sub-level UL during the animation:

**Using Floats:**

Right, I was trying to do it without floats.
I'm trying to stick with the animation function.

Safari bugs out and flashes the sub ul during the animation.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
ul {
  background-color: yellow;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 1em;
  float: left;
}
ul li {
  background-color: aqua;
  float: left;
}
ul li ul {
  background-color: blue;
}
ul li ul li {
  background-color: green;
}
a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
-->
</style>
```

**Original Post:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>untitled</title>
       <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    ul{ 
        list-style: none;
        background-color: yellow;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

    ul li {
        background-color: aqua;
        display: inline;


    }

    ul li ul { 
        background-color: blue;
              }


    ul li ul li {
        background-color: green;    
    }

    a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;

    }
    -->
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
           var $current = null;
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("ul li ul").hide(); // hide submenus by default on load

           $("ul li a").click(function(){
              var $sub = $(this).next(); 
              if ($sub.css("display") == "none")
              {
                 if ($current != null)
                    $current.animate({ width: 'hide' }); // if you want to only show one sub at a time
                 $sub.animate({ width: 'show' }); 
                 $current = $sub;
              }
              else
              {
                 $sub.animate({ width: 'hide' });
                 $current = null;
              }
           });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <ul>
            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 2</a>

                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A4</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 3</a>
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level B1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level B2</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 4</a>
            </li>
    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27262010/1922144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you would like to have first and second menu level in one line (horizontal) ?

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul{
        list-style: none;
        background-color: yellow;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
    }
    ul li {
        background-color: aqua;
        float: left;
    }
    ul li ul {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    ul li ul li {
        background-color: green;
    }
    a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but Safari bugs out and flashes the sub ul during the animation.

Comment: Don't use inline, elements are better if they are blocked. Try fixed height on other ul.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "display:inline" would do the trick - but the animate function is setting the display to "block" instead of "inline".

If it is okay to "snap" into place instead of animating, you could do this instead.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>untitled</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        ul{list-style:none;background-color:yellow;margin:0;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;display:inline;}
        li ul{display:inline;}
        ul li{background-color:aqua;display:inline;}
        ul li ul{background-color: blue;}
        ul li ul li{background-color: green;}
        a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active{color: black;text-decoration: none;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $current = null;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("ul li ul").hide(); // hide submenus by default on load

            $("ul li a").click(function() {
                var $sub = $(this).next();
                if ($sub.css("display") == "none") {
                    if ($current != null)
                        //$current.animate({ width: 'hide' }); // if you want to only show one sub at a time
                    $current.removeAttr("display").attr({ style: "display:none;" });
                    $sub.removeAttr("style").attr({ display: "inline" });
                    $current = $sub;
                }
                else {
                    $sub.removeAttr("display").attr({ style: "display:none;" });
                    $current = null;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 2</a>

                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A4</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 3</a>
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level B1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level B2</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 4</a>
            </li>
    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, but I'm trying to stick with the animation function.

Comment: You're welcome - I just can't seem to figure out how to override the display:block that the animate function uses. Its frustrating because if you change it using firebug it displays perfectly. I just don't think the animate function will allow you to use display inline. Looking for workaround... :)

Comment: This may be the wrong path for me to be going down - it may not be possible to animate an inline element in the first place...

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_animations_set_the_display_style_to_block.3F

Comment: At least it's a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's fun to build yourself. It's also fun to use this awesomeness:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: Does the jQuery accordian allow you to display the content horizontally?