# how to make jquery ui accordion horizontal?

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

This what I have done so far.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Open on hoverintent</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demos.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                event: "click hoverintent",
                heightStyle: "content"
            });
        });

        $.event.special.hoverintent = {
            setup: function() {
                $(this).bind("mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler);
            },
            teardown: function() {
                $(this).unbind("mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler);
            },
            handler: function(event) {
                var currentX, currentY, timeout,
                        args = arguments,
                        target = $(event.target),
                        previousX = event.pageX,
                        previousY = event.pageY;

                function track(event) {
                    currentX = event.pageX;
                    currentY = event.pageY;
                }
                ;

                function clear() {
                    target
                            .unbind("mousemove", track)
                            .unbind("mouseout", clear);
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                }

                function handler() {
                    var prop,
                            orig = event;

                    if ((Math.abs(previousX - currentX) +
                            Math.abs(previousY - currentY)) < 7) {
                        clear();

                        event = $.Event("hoverintent");
                        for (prop in orig) {
                            if (!(prop in event)) {
                                event[ prop ] = orig[ prop ];
                            }
                        }
                        // Prevent accessing the original event since the new event
                        // is fired asynchronously and the old event is no longer
                        // usable (#6028)
                        delete event.originalEvent;

                        target.trigger(event);
                    } else {
                        previousX = currentX;
                        previousY = currentY;
                        timeout = setTimeout(handler, 100);
                    }
                }

                timeout = setTimeout(handler, 100);
                target.bind({
                    mousemove: track,
                    mouseout: clear
                });
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="jq">

    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <div>
            content
        </div>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <div>
           content
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to turn it to horizontal? I have tried other codes that i have found on the web but the limitations are the length and width are fixed and of course the design. I prefer the default design. :)

Comment: use another plugin. For example: http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/

Comment: You can use [jqueryrotate](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) to rotate it. Alternatively, you can write your own rotate function but making that browser-independent is a bitch. [See here](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/source/browse/trunk/jQueryRotate.js#281).

Comment: I got my answer. In this link http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-horizontal-accordion-using-target-selector/

It uses css but there is this limitation, the container can't resize automatically according to the content but the container can be easily resized. For now, it is adequate for me but however if anyone have a solution to make it resizable according to the content i greatly appreciate it. :)

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27262010/1922144